# Zoom to layer after CQL in WFS format

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I'm using a dropdownlist to CQL each WFS layer. How to zoom extend to the selected CQL layer?

```
$("#district").change(function() {
     
    
    var statekod=document.getElementById("district").value;
    var cqlFilter='ngdp='+ statekod ;
    
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function() {
      return 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/TM/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&' +
                'typename=TM:Daerah&' +
                'CQL_FILTER='+ cqlFilter + '&' +    
                'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +                    
                'format_options=callback:gotFetch';
            
                
    }
    
    
    
    
    
  });
        
        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
            width: 2 
          })
          
        }),
        
      });   

    
        
        
    map.addLayer(vector);
    //console.log(vector);
    
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for the load or refresh to complete then you can fit the view to the extent of the features in the source

```
vectorSource.on('featuresloadend', function() {
  map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
});
```

Comment: thanks it works sir...one more thing if to clear previous cql before adding new cql i need to add what type of function? i try .refresh() not working